# Use unit of work in presentation layer ASP.NET Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

I'm using a combination of unit of work and repository pattern in clean architecture and ASP.NET Core 5 (for keeping one connection to database in multiple layers), but I'm sending unit of work repository from controller to application layer.

Is it ok or not?

I've tried this and my program works correctly but I'm not sure if this way is correct?

Comment: Would need to see more. In a modern app, UoW and repo wouldn't be in the controller, only in an application/orchestration layer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.